# User agent string with HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl

I am using `HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url)`, but the server blocks me due to incompatible **user agent** string. How can I change the user agent string with `HTML::TreeBuilder` to use `new_from_url($url)` directly, without a workaround of getting web content by the traditional way?

Comment: Depending on your actual ask, [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org) may give you the configurability and DOM parsing that you need. It's interface doesn't have the same annoying walls that LWP has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to set that in `new_from_url()`.  You'll have to load `LWP::UserAgent` yourself and set the user agent string.  Then you can parse the content with `new_from_content()`.

However, here's a direct link to the [new_from_url](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Tree/source/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm#L116) code.  You can use that as the basis of your own `new()` method so that your program flow will read the same way.

So something like:

```perl
sub HTML::TreeBuilder::my_new_from_url {
  # copy and augment new_from_url
  ...
}

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->my_new_from_url($url, { useragent => "foo" });
```

Now all of that right-way-to-do-it notwithstanding, you can play a dirty trick on `LWP::UserAgent` by overriding its private `_agent` method that stores the default user agent string.  But be aware that you have voided the warranty and all broken module behavior is on you.

```perl
#the original 
sub _agent { "libwww-perl/$VERSION" }
```

Define in your code:

```perl
use LWP::UserAgent ();
sub LWP::UserAgent::_agent { "Mozilla forever" }
```

Or, more deviously:

```perl
use LWP::UserAgent ();

my $tree = do {
  local *LWP::UserAgent::_agent = sub { "Mozilla forever" };
  HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url);

};
```